# How can I target all elements in Ant Design?

Tags: css, antd

I would like to remove all rounded corners in my application using the Ant Design framework.

I tried adding different permutations of `ant*` in my `index.css` but i cannot get it to work.

**index.css**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}

.ant {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant Design allows you to customize our design tokens in order to meet the needs of UI diversity from business and brand, including primary color, border radius, border color, etc..

Here is [documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme)

```
@border-radius-base: 0px; // major border radius
```

Or override above

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.less'; // Import Ant Design styles by less entry
@import 'your-theme-file.less'; // variables to override above
```